# Setting a `margin` property to a `fixed` element with `z-index: 1`

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

There's a list, and a comment field. Comment field is `fixed` to the page bottom. When the list is long, page scroll applies.
I want the bottom of the list be always at a certain vertical distance from the top of the comment field. Of course, I can apply the `margin-bottom` property to the `.meaning` class (which shapes the list), but this margin may be not enough, if the comment field contains 2 or 3 lines of text (i.e., too high for set margin).
So imo it makes more sense to set `margin-top` to the *comment* field instead. However, possibly due to the `z-index: 1` property of the comment field, `margin-top` doesn't work either.

[Here](https://jsbin.com/wudihifewu/edit?html,css,output) is the JS Bin, just in case.

```css
.meaning {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: item;
  hyphens: auto;
  font-size: calc(0.7em + 1.5vw);
}

.meaning > li {
  position: relative;
}

.meaning > li::before {
  content: counter(item);
  counter-increment: item;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: calc(-0.7em - 2.5vw);            
}

.meaning-word {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.sentences {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  font-size: calc(0.7em + 1.5vw);
  margin-top: 30px;                 
}

.sentences > li.sentence-en {
  color: #5d78e5;
}

.sentences > li.sentence-de {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.comment {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fdf1d1;
  color: #f92504;
  font-size: calc(0.5em + 2vw);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 4vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    
  <ol class="meaning">
    <li class="meaning-word">Meaning1</li>
      <ul class="sentences">
        <li class="sentence-en">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li class="sentence-de">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</li>
      </ul>
    <li class="meaning-word">Meaning2</li>
      <ul class="sentences">
        <li class="sentence-en">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li class="sentence-de">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</li>
    </ul>
  </ol>
  
    <div class="comment">
    <p>This is line 1 of text information.</p>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position: sticky` instead then you can easily set a `margin-top` since the element remains in the flow

```css
.meaning {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: item;
  hyphens: auto;
  font-size: calc(0.7em + 1.5vw);
}

.meaning>li {
  position: relative;
}

.meaning>li::before {
  content: counter(item);
  counter-increment: item;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: calc(-0.7em - 2.5vw);
}

.meaning-word {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.sentences {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  font-size: calc(0.7em + 1.5vw);
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.sentences>li.sentence-en {
  color: #5d78e5;
}

.sentences>li.sentence-de {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.comment {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fdf1d1;
  color: #f92504;
  font-size: calc(0.5em + 2vw);
  margin-top: 40px;
  padding: 5px 4vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<ol class="meaning">
    <li class="meaning-word">Meaning1</li>
    <ul class="sentences">
      <li class="sentence-en">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li class="sentence-de">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked
        up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus
        Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a
        line in section 1.10.32.</li>
    </ul>
    <li class="meaning-word">Meaning2</li>
    <ul class="sentences">
      <li class="sentence-en">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li class="sentence-de">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked
        up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus
        Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a
        line in section 1.10.32.</li>
    </ul>
  </ol>

  <div class="comment">
    <p>This is line 1 of text information.</p>
  </div>
```